# Conditional joining tables based on parameterized value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to have a conditional join based on parameter; for example:

```
//PSEUDE CODE:
DECLARE @condition bit
SET @condition=1 or 0 

SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.SomeColumn = tableB.SomeColumn 
if @condition = 0 THEN 
   INNER JOIN tableC ON tableC.SomeCOlumn = TableA.SomeColumn 
ELSE
   INNER JOIN tableD ON tableD.SomeColumn=TableA.someColumn
```

Thank you

Comment: No not really. If you cold tell a bit more about what you want to achieve there are probably many other ways of getting the result you want. You could have two queries and use an `if` to decide what query to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You can build a varchar containing your query and use `exec` to execute them.

> Executes a command string or character string within a Transact-SQL batch, or one of the following modules: system stored procedure, user-defined stored procedure, CLR stored procedure, scalar-valued user-defined function, or extended stored procedure.

#### Sample

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
DECLARE @condition bit
SET @condition=1 

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.SomeColumn=tableB.SomeColumn'

IF (@condition = 1) 
BEGIN 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' INNER JOIN tableC ON tableC.SomeCOlumn=TableA.SomeColumn'
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' INNER JOIN tableD ON tableD.SomeColumn=TableA.someColumn'
    END

exec(@SQL)
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with dynamic query

```
declare @sql_str varchar(500)
if @contidion=0
@sql_str='INNER JOIN tableC ON tableC.SomeCOlumn=TableA.SomeColumn'
else
@sql_str='INNER JOIN tableD ON tableD.SomeColumn=TableA.someColumn'

exec('SELECT * FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB on 
 tableA.SomeColumn=tableB.SomeColumn' +@sql_str)
```

Comment: I thought of that but my stored procedure is huge and using dynamic query complicates a lot of things, wondering is there other way; thank you anyhow :)

Comment: @Avicena00: you are welcome. I dont think apart from this conditional joining is possible

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, see [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/03/Conditional-Joins.aspx)

But in these kind of situations I'd rather use multiple if statements if your conditions are predefined and not too many. This is a lot easier to read and maintain.

```
If (condition1)
 Select * From tblA
Else If (condition2)
 Select * From tblA Inner Join tblB ...
Else If (condition3)
 .....
```